# Prioritizing element classes in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there a way to prioritize classes for elements or an easy way to insert a new class when you want to add one?

I have multiple states of elements and would like to be able to show states as a priority but it looks like first in wins all the time.

Right now, you call the `addClass()` method to add a class, but that just sets a key/value on the `classes` field.  Should I be adding `!important` to styles in order for it to work as a CSS style?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem.StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organise your stylesheet blocks in increasing order of precedence.  The last matching block wins.

See http://js.cytoscape.org/#style